# Displaying results for items that have value in one of the field in the table

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to display content based on th value in the table field? Lets say that I have a field in my table called label, which isnt obligatory to fill in, can I filter the content based on if that field is populated for specific item? Item that has that field populated would be displayed and item with that field left blank wouldnt.

model.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  price = models.FloatField()
  discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
  category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
  label = models.ManyToManyField(Label, blank=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
  description = models.TextField()
  image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py:

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  context = {
    'item_list': item_list,
  }
  return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter

```
item_list = Item.objects.filter(label = your_label_item)
```

if you want to get all Items where label is not null you can use this

```
item_list = Item.objects.filter(label__isnull = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the `Item`s where `label` is not None? Then you could try this:

```py
item_list = Item.objects.exclude(label=None)
```